# idiom which means rain heavily

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for a dramatic equivalent for "raining cats and dogs". I want to write down a sentence like this:

***And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and it started...***

Obviously, "raining cats and dogs" does not work in that sentence in terms of register. What can I say? I already know verbs like "shower" and "pour" but I'm looking for an idiom.

Comment: Well, there's "torrent" -- "A torrent of rain came down".

Comment: Thanks a lot. A very good suggestion.

Comment: *It's pouring down* or *it's tipping down* or *bucketing down*.

Comment: There was much amusement in Britain when a TV weather announcer said it had been ['pissing down'](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/this-britain/and-now-for-the-weather-forecast-its-pissing-down-413285.html), but the only a few complaints materialised; instead there were lots of emails expressing amusement.

Comment: I would not recommend *pissing down* for this context.

Comment: If you want to go biblical, *the heavens opened up*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***[deluge](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deluge)*** could be useful.

Per Lexico:

> **NOUN**
>
> 1.2  A heavy fall of rain.
>         ‘a deluge of rain hit the plains’

While it's more common, in my experience, as a noun (in regards to rain), it is also a verb:

> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Overwhelm with a flood.
>
>    ‘caravans were deluged by the heavy rains’

In your example, you could say:

> And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and a deluge...

or

> And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and they were struck by a deluge of rain...

Answer (score 1):

"And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and it started lashing down."

[**"lash down"**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lash+down) - (Of rain) to fall very heavily.

> - "torrential rain was **lashing down**"
> - "It's been **lashing down** for the last hour or so."
> - "It's dry at the moment, but with how dark those clouds are it looks like it could **lash down** at any moment."

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference number : 3](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/9-useful-english-phrases-to-say-when-its-raining/)

> **And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and it**
>   **really started coming down.**

**EDITED**

Removed the 'out there' part from the sentence as it was optional

Comment: We're not told we're inside. And even if we were, 'out there' is more immediate than sounds natural in a past-tense narrative.

Comment: Nor are we told we are outside. Its an idiom, it can be used in a general format. When we say its raining cats and dogs it doesn't means that cats and dogs are falling from sky.

Comment: To me, the collocation is ***coming down***.  “out there” isn’t an integral part of it.  “*The sky turned gray and it really started coming down*” is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could say: 
*And then mother nature became furious. The sky turned gray and it started **[bucketing down](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/bucket-down)** — CED*

Alternatively, you could say: ...*it started **tipping down or pouring down**.*

---

Or

**The heavens open:**
It suddenly starts to rain very heavily — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/the_heavens_open)

Answer (score 0):

Another phrase to mean "raining heavily" is ***raining buckets***, as though someone were throwing buckets of water at you from the sky.

To describe a heavy rain that starts suddenly, you could say ***the sky opened (up)***.